# Django: Display all possible form errors

Tags: django, django-2.1

I have a Form in Django 2.1.

Is there a possibility to render all possible errors in the testserver?

I would like to verify if they all render nicely.

Especially those that are hard to produce such as `non_field_errors`.

I know that it's possible to access a forms error list in the view.

Answer (score 0):

for errors related to form not field:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

Comment: Thats the implementation, but how do I trigger them to appear?
Same for HiddenField errors. Is there a way to let all error messages appear?

Comment: It would render where you put it in the template

Comment: Say you had a contact form with fields for the user to enter an email address and phone number. You don't care which one the user provides, but they must enter one of them. If they submit the form with both fields empty, that would be a non-field error.@ohlr

Comment: Yes, but only if there are actual errors, when submitting the form. If I leave all fields blank, only form.field.errors are displayed. I would like all possible errors that the form can produce to show up.

Comment: If you want to create error ,then do something that produces the error.But if there is more that one error it should show up exaclty like you do in the template.It is quite intuitive and no need to double check

Comment: you can use a if tag and display a p tag to see what type of error is actually displayihng if you want

Comment: Thats correct, but than I don't have the correct error text, but some arbitrary text.
The thing is, I want to check if the error texts, fit into my form and render nicely. Since I don't know all possible errors I was asking for a way to enforce all errors to show up.